# What are these commands making KVM run as non root actually doing?

Tags: linux, kvm

I am following [a guide for making KVM run as non-root](https://github.com/casualsnek/cassowary/blob/main/docs/1-virt-manager.md#making-kvm-run-without-root-access) in order to make a piece of software called [cassowary](https://github.com/casualsnek/cassowary) work correctly. The issue is that I am trying to execute the following commands on kinoite and therefore cannot modify the /etc directory.

```
$ sudo sed -i "s/#user = \"root\"/user = \"$(id -un)\"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
$ sudo sed -i "s/#group = \"root\"/group = \"$(id -gn)\"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
$ sudo usermod -a -G kvm $(id -un)
$ sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $(id -un)
$ sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
$ sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

What are these commands doing and what can I do to make them functional on an immutable distro.

Comment: examine each line separately ... determine the result if executing each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $ sudo sed -i "s/#user = \"root\"/user = \"$(id -un)\"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
> ```

`id -un` outputs the name of the user running that command.

`sudo` (`s`witch `u`ser and `do`) is a command to run another command as a different user. When not specified, that's generally `root` a user with super-user privileges to whom regular access control doesn't apply, so for instance who can modify any file on the filesystem. You'll have to have been explicitly granted the right to run commands as that user and to provide credentials confirming who you are for that to work.

`sed` is a `s`tream `ed`itor. Some `sed` implementations have a `-i` option for it to operate on the contents of files `i`n-place, so it can be used to edit files the same way you'd edit *streams*.

The `sed` command (from the early 70s) understands a very simple programming language. In that languages there's a `s/pattern/replacement/flags` command, the same as in the `ed` text editor to substitute a replacement for strings matching a pattern.

Here the pattern is `#user = "root"` and replacement is `user = "<output-of-the-id-command>"`, `g` means it can be done as many times as needed per line (which doesn't make sense here, but is likely harmless).

In effect, that will uncomment the `#user = "root"` line in that file an replace `root` with the invoking user.

That file it edits is the [configuration for the QEMU driver for libvirt](https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#location-of-configuration-files). The file has:

```
# The user for QEMU processes run by the system instance. It can be
# specified as a user name or as a user id. The qemu driver will try to
# parse this value first as a name and then, if the name doesn't exist,
# as a user id.
#
# Since a sequence of digits is a valid user name, a leading plus sign
# can be used to ensure that a user id will not be interpreted as a user
# name.
#
# By default libvirt runs VMs as non-root and uses AppArmor profiles
# to provide host protection and VM isolation. While AppArmor
# continues to provide this protection when the VMs are running as
# root, /dev/vhost-net, /dev/vhost-vsock and /dev/vhost-scsi access is
# allowed by default in the AppArmor security policy, so malicious VMs
# running as root would have direct access to this file. If changing this
# to run as root, you may want to remove this access from
# /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu. For more information, see:
# https://launchpad.net/bugs/1815910
# https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2019-April/msg00750.html
#
# Some examples of valid values are:
#
#       user = "qemu"   # A user named "qemu"
#       user = "+0"     # Super user (uid=0)
#       user = "100"    # A user named "100" or a user with uid=100
#
#user = "root"
```

See also https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#posix-users-groups.

So that tells `libvirtd` to run `qemu` as the user you run that command as.

> ```
> $ sudo sed -i "s/#group = \"root\"/group = \"$(id -gn)\"/g" /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf
> ```

Same for the `group` setting there.

> ```
> $ sudo usermod -a -G kvm $(id -un)
> ```

That adds the current user as a member of the `kvm` Unix group. That group has read+write access to /dev/kvm which qemu needs to use the KVM hypervisor capabilities.

> ```
> $ sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $(id -un)
> ```

Same for the `libvirt` group whose membership allows managing system-level VMs.

> ```
> $ sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
> ```

Restarts the `libvirtd` daemon for those settings to be applied.

> ```
> $ sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
> ```

Disables apparmor for the libvirtd service, relaxing a lot of things that libvirtd and some of the commands it run would otherwise not be able to do, some of which is presumably is needed for qemu to be run as non-root properly.

> What are these commands doing and what can I do to make them functional on an immutable distro.

That will most likely depend on the distro and how exactly it is *immutable*.

Comment: I am using an ostree based distro which means everything but /var is read only. How this works in practice is [best explained by fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora-silverblue/technical-information/#filesystem-layout).